# algorithm to calculate code for an image

Tags: java, image-processing, hash, cbir

I am working on a content-based image retrieval system on a distributed environment, I need an algorithm that takes as input an image and gives me a code for the image, this code should be such that it can be used to match visually similar images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on kind of images, one workable alternative would be  invariant moments
( either hu,   or zernike )

We use this method in [javaocr library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/), feel free to grab code from there.

Main advantage of invariant moments with cluster mathing is that it provides distance from cluster centers ( like:  this is 90% cucumber but 20% apple )

Answer (score 1):

you can create an Image Hash  as described [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?reload=true&arnumber=5715530)

Comment: I'm pretty sure hashes can't be used to match with similar things.

Comment: @ZachLatta, you're thinking of cryptographic hashes, where small changes in the input produce massive changes in the hash - called an avalanche effect. With image hashing, you often want small changes in the image to produce small (or zero) changes in the hash. Perceptual hashing techniques try to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are talking about face recognition. If itś then these are few algorithms which are used on image processing.

1. [Eigenface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface)
2. [Elastic Bunch Graph Matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_Bunch_Graph_Matching)
3. [Principal Component Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_Component_Analysis)

Answer (score 0):

You can use locally aware bloom hash, this is an implementation of phash in java by Elliot Shepherd: http://pastebin.com/Pj9d8jt5